# Non-convex quadratic program over the standard simplex

Tags: optimization, numerical-optimization, quadratic-programming, non-convex-optimization

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{maximize} & x'Ax\\ \text{subject to} & \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i = 1\\ & x \in [0,1]^n\end{array}$$

where the objective is not concave. I want to write an iterative procedure to do this. Suggestions?

Comment: Do you mean the objective is not *concave*?  That's the kind of objective you want when you're maximizing.  If so, I think this will be tricky.  Any iterative procedure is likely to find a local maximum, not a global maximum.

Comment: yeah concave, I mean it's not concave. How should I proceed?